# List item from SQL based on user level by MVC 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and a SQL database. I need help about how to list data from the database based on the user level.

The Administrator can see all the items in all the sections and the internal sections.

The super user can see only the items in his section.

The normal user can see only the items in his Internal section.

How can I do that in ASP.NET MVC 5?

I worked with:

```
[Authorize-admin]
```

But I need more

[image]

See the screenshot please.. thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a multi tenant application?

Comment: Yes Preben multi users roles

Comment: Not multi user, [mutlitenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) ?

Comment: Yes it is Preben and thank you i had solved it by using EntityFrame work.